# if (isset) to hide an element until it is set

Tags: php, html, if-statement, isset

I am attempting to hide an image box until a file has been set within my file upload code. Right now it shows the `$preview` image box regardless if a file has been set.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Change your profile picture <br><input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile" onchange="readURL(this);">
    <?php
    $preview_file = '<input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile" onchange="readURL(this);">';
    $preview =  '<img width="300px" height="200px" id="file" src="#" alt="your image">';
    if (empty($preview_file)) {
        '';
    } else {
        echo $preview;
    } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Well, `$preview_file` will obviously never be empty, since you explicitly assign a string to it only two lines further up.

Comment: I think you're getting confused about what runs where. This isn't possible directly with PHP. PHP runs on the server, not in the client. By the time you see the page, PHP has finished (give or take). Dynamic on-page interactions need done by JS (with AJAX where required).

Comment: It will do, you are setting `$preview_file` and then 2 lines below it are checking to see if it is empty, it wont be.

Comment: Well when I mean set, I mean when I have searched for a file and chosen one. Not sure what the best route it then?

Comment: under the `PHP`Tag, Jquery answer has been accepted. There is something funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of PHP conditions you can achieve this using jquery.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Change your profile picture <br>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile">
    <img width="300px" height="200px" id="file" src="#" alt="your image" style="display: none;">
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Upload">
</form>
```

In `img` tag set `style="display:none"` and onchange event of file input make the image tag show as below.

Remove `onchange` from the file upload element and instead use jquery `change` event as below. Your readURL function will be as it is.

```
$(".inputbarfile").change(function(){
  $("#file").show();
  readURL(this);
});
```

Comment: But he wants with php

Comment: @downvoter why you have made down vote? The answer is seems helpful to SO even. Please think before down vote.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with PHP only, your code should look like below ( except the security for $_POST htmlstrips, escapes):

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['file'])):?>
    <?php $file = $_POST['file']; //#SECURE You should escape here ?>
    File:  <?php echo $file; ?>
    Image: <img width="300px" height="200px" id="file" src="path/to/image/<?php echo $file ?>" alt="your image" />
<?php endif; ?>

<form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Change your profile picture <br>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="inputbarfile" onchange="readURL(this);" />
    <input type="submit" name="create" value="Upload" />
</form>
```